# Trying to modify some info in a List

Tags: c#

I have a method

```
 void ModifierNomPlat(ref List<string> p_plats)
```

What I am trying to do is to modify an entry (the user will give the number he wants to modify). Right now I have this, but I am not sure how to compare the user entry with the List index.

```
        for (int i = 0; p_plats.Count > i; i++)
        {
            WriteLine(i + 1 + " : " + p_plats[i]);
        }
        Write("\n");

        int noPlat = ObtenirNoPlatExistantouAnnulation(p_plats);

        if (noPlat == -1)
            return;

        int indicePlat = p_plats.FindIndex(p => p_plats[] == noPlat);
```

The method `ObtenirNoPlatExistantouAnnulation` only asks the number with validation I don't think it's relevant for you to help me.

Comment: there is nothing in your code you showed us that would require you to use `ref`. If you don't have `p_plats = ...` in the function there is no reason to use `ref`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying an element in a list based on its position is the same way how you modify an array element based on its index.

```
p_plats[index] = "Your Value";
```